# cambiar la imagen el index de un stakedWidget mediante un QcomboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Buenas noches tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from tabla import tabla_style

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("new_exe.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.b_close.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
        self.b_min.clicked.connect(lambda:self.showMinimized())
        if self.combo.currentIndex() == 0:
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        elif self.combo.currentIndex()== 1:
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)




app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

y lo que estoy tratando es que cuando cambie el valor de qcombobox cambie el index del stakedwidget sin embargo no funciona
Alguna sugerencia¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu debes usar un señal para hacer el cambio ya que tu verificación solo se hace en el constructor por unica vez.

Asumiendo que el QComboBox tiene la misma cantidad de items que páginas el QStackedWidget solo es necesario conectar la señal `currentIndexChanged`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, flags=Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        uic.loadUi("new_exe.ui",self)

        self.b_close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.b_min.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Observación:** No abuses de las funciones lambda, en el caso de PyQt es mejor hacer una conección directa ya que se ahorra recursos y se aumenta la rápidez.